# math expression in a sentence using cat()?

Tags: r

```
p=seq(0,1,by=0.001)

x=log(p/(1-p))

cat(sep="", "Given p is a number between 0 and 1, log((p/(1-p))), goes from (", min(x), ") to (", max(x), ").\n")
```

Here is the output:

Given p is a number between 0 and 1, log((p/(1-p))), goes from (-Inf) to (Inf).

However, I want to change log((p/(1-p))) to the math fraction expression like this

[please click the link to see][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuPSZ.png

I tried expression(log(frac(p, 1-p))), but this does not work

Comment: cat will yield text output only. Use it in a plot (e.g. ggtitle()) or notebook should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

p=seq(0,1,by=0.001)
x=log(p/(1-p))
val1 = format(min(x),digits=3)
val2 = format(max(x),digits=3)

eq = bquote(paste("Given p is a number between 0 and 1, ", 
                  log(frac(p, 1-p)), 
                  " goes from (",
                  .(val1), ") to (", .(val2), ")"
                 ))
ggplot() + ggtitle(eq)
```

Comment: No problem - please accept answer so the system can see it has been answered.